# MAAS CLI - user-data not firing on boot

Tags: maas

I am attempting to deploy a test machine in my lab through the MAAS cli. The machine will go through the deployment, however the Cloud-Init User-Data does not fire on boot.

```
[user-data]
    #cloud-config
    user: terminal
    password: 
    chpasswd: {expire: False}
    ssh_pwauth: True
    package_update: true
    package_upgrade: true
    runcmd:
      - 'curl -L https://bootstrap.saltstack.com -o install_salt.sh'
      - 'sh install_salt.sh -A 192.168.1.155'
      - 'apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 78BD65473CB3BD13'
```

[CLI CMDS]

user_data=$(base64 -w0 /home/aweare/cloud-init/user-data)
maas aweare machine deploy mktpfp user_data=$user_data

I was using the following as a resource:

https://discourse.maas.io/t/customizing-maas-deployments-with-cloud-init/165

[Update]

I had installed MAAS using SNAP. After installing via Packages it works as expected. Thank you all for viewing